Example of a Recursive Algorithm with a Call Stack Space Complexity Beyond O(n)
I’m specifically interested in call stack space complexity, not the space used by additional data structures.
Any insights or examples would be greatly appreciated!

Seems simple enough, f(n, i) = if i<n*n then f(n, i+1) else i.
